# Filter several models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Lets say i have three models that i want to return as json:

```
Car:  id, name, age, color, brand, created_at
Bike: id, name, size, tire,        created_at
Bus:  id, ps, consumption          created_at
```

So what i want to do is sort the three models by `created at`:

(My imaginary code): `[Car,Bike,Bus].sort.order("created_at DESC")`
So that at the end i have all three models in one active record Association! Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible

For example, if your model object `a` has all three associations, you can do

```
[a.cars, a.bikes, a.buses].flatten.sort_by{|obj| -obj.created_at}
```

Comment: Very good answer! But would you recommend my something like this?